# Regular expression to match words that doesn't start with #

Tags: python, regex

I need Regex to match words that doesn't start with #

Example:

```
#Repost @edbyellen
 #EDEllenDeGeneres rugs so cozy you can walk on them, nap, on them, sleep on them you get the picture
Now available in select retailers in the US, crafted by @LoloiRugs. #EDbyLoloi
```

I want a regex to match words like this:

```
@edbyellen
rugs so cozy you can walk on them, nap, on them, sleep on them you get the picture
Now available in select retailers in the US, crafted by @LoloiRugs.
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Is there any particular reason you feel that you need a regex for this, rather than splitting the text on whitespace and seeing if the string starts with `#`?

Comment: So something like `\b[^#].+\b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways, one of them:

```
import re

text = """#Repost @edbyellen
 #EDEllenDeGeneres rugs so cozy you can walk on them, nap, on them, sleep on them you get the picture
Now available in select retailers in the US, crafted by @LoloiRugs. #EDbyLoloi"""

print re.sub(r'#[^# ]+', '', text)
```

Output:

```
 @edbyellen
  rugs so cozy you can walk on them, nap, on them, sleep on them you get the picture
Now available in select retailers in the US, crafted by @LoloiRugs.
```

Feedback from [Yoav Glazner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741460/yoav-glazner), to see matching strings:

```
print re.sub(r'#[^# ]+', '', text).split()
```

Output:

```
['@edbyellen', 'rugs', 'so', 'cozy', 'you', 'can', 'walk', 'on', 'them,', 'nap,', 'on', 'them,', 'sleep', 'on', 'them', 'you', 'get', 'the', 'picture', 'Now', 'available', 'in', 'select', 'retailers', 'in', 'the', 'US,', 'crafted', 'by', '@LoloiRugs.']
```

Comment: You should add a split after the sub to get separated "matches"

Answer (score 1):

without regex:

```
for line in lines:
  for word in line.split():
    if not word.startswith('#'):
      print(word)
  print()
```

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
\B([a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!;)
```

I think this is useful.